# How to switch between multiple content views and view controllers using a single container view?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Apologies if this is more of a best-practice/your-opinion-wanted question but I'm not even sure whether this thing is supported and the past few hours on Google yielded little useful insight. Anyways.

I have a view controller in which I have a few controls that need to stay the same, and a number of others that need to change depending on the state of those "fixed" controls. I thought this could be the perfect job for a view container: I can design any number of different view controllers with different controls and stuff, and then I can switch between them placing them inside the view container.

So I set the whole thing up, Auto Layout and all the accessories, and the layout thing works (which means I've done a number of unorthodox tests that confirms that if I resize the view container, all the other "fixed" views move accordingly. I'm super happy with it.

Except that there seems to be no way to embed multiple view controllers at the same time directly from the Storyboard and having the containing (external, super, whatever) view controller perform the appropriate segues. Ok, then, let's do it programmatically, and here's where the best of my knowledge stops.

I tried with some incredibly dumb code from the top of my head, something like

```
for(UIViewController *vc in [self childViewControllers]) {
    // I know, I'm just prototyping here...
    [vc.view removeFromSuperview];
    [vc removeFromParentViewController];
}
UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"B_Screen"];
[self addChildViewController:vc];
[_containerView addSubview:vc.view];
```

but the `_containerView` doesn't seem to resize appropriately. This may be due to the fact that che content views have all a "Greater than or Equal" constraint from the last view to the bottom of the container view, so if my original content view is taller or shorter than the one I instantiate with `B_Screen`, the `_containerView` will keep the size of the original one.

At this point, I'd even appreciate a RTFM, if only you could point to the right manual (and yes, I've read the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS" (although I may have missed some bits, so feel free to slap my face with them.

Once the whole thing works, I'd like to set up fancy animations, like fade-out/fade-in or something like that, but I think I can work on that on my own.

**EDIT:** Upon closer inspection, two things seem to be happening: the content view is correctly replaced but it doesn't thightly "hug" its content, which means there's a rather large space at the bottom of the view, between its bottom side and the "last" view. This is however kind of obvious since I've got a constraint between the bottom side of the content view and the bottom side of the last contained view that is of a "greater or equal than" type, which means that 20 is good, 15 is bad, but 200 is good as well as 20. However if I set it to something more strict, like a proper "equal", Auto Layout complains all over the place that there are conflicting constraints. This may very well be a "bug" (or feature, sounds like expected behaviour) of AL.

The second thing that seems to happen is that the vertical spacing constraint between the bottom side of the container view, and the "first" view that's below it, belonging to the "external" container, is silently broken (AL says nothing in the console like it would if it had to break constraints or something like that), which means that the container view just covers up whatever is supposed to be otherwise moved down. I'm inside a scroll view, so I don't really care about how tall my interface becomes.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but maybe what you're missing are calls to:

- `- (void)willMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent`
- `- (void)didMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent`

They're somewhat described in the section [Implementing a Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81)

Comment: The docs also say that there's no need to override or call these two methods, but I'll look closer.

Comment: Are you sure of that? [didMoveToParentViewController:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didMoveToParentViewController:) description: `If you are implementing your own container view controller, it must call the didMoveToParentViewController: method of the child view controller after the transition to the new controller is complete or, if there is no transition, immediately after calling the addChildViewController: method.
`

Answer (score 0):

What I did in a very similar situation (permanent Navigation bar with two exchangeable UIViewControllers, was to use a **UIPageViewController**.

Store it as a property like

```
@property (nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageController;
```

To prevent switching the view controllers via swipe, set it up with page curl and disable the gesture recognizers

```
// Somewhere in view did load
UIViewController *initialSubVC = [[UIViewController alloc] ...];
self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

// Set initial view controller
[self.pageController setViewControllers:@[initialSubVC] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

// Disable manual swiping
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.pageController.gestureRecognizers) {
    recognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```

To switch between your view controllers, you can again use the following code, maybe triggered by a button click

```
[self.pageController setViewControllers:@[otherSubVC] direction:0 animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Maybe you can setup all your view controllers in view did load and store them in an array.

I am not really sure whether you have to set a delegate and implement the delegate methods since there is no swiping.

Comment: Could be, except that I thought that pages in a UIPageViewController are all the same height, and my different interfaces are most definitely not.

Comment: I though I could force a view to resize to fit its intrinsic content size.